# How to get a product collection which have 'feature' attribute = Yes?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-collection

I created a Yes or No attribute called 'feature'. I have a Product Tab slider on the home page. On that tab it had Best Seller, Latest Product and Latest Deal. I want to add Feature Product (product is 'feature' attribute is set to "Yes") also on that tab.

```
<div class="container">
<?php
/**
 * Tab Links
 */
$class = $_compareUrl = $currentDate = '';
?>
    <div class="best-new-product-tab">
        <ul class="TabNav">
            <li id="defaultTab"><a href="#bestsellingproducts"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Bestsellers'); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#newproducts"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Latest Products'); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#deal"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Latest Deal'); ?></a></li>




        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php 
    /**
     * Best seller products
     */?>
    <div class="best-new-product-tab-content">
        <div id="bestsellingproducts">
         <?php $bestSellingCollection = $this->bestSellerCollection ();
                $categoryCount = count ( $bestSellingCollection );
                if ($categoryCount >= 1) { ?>                   

                <div class="products-grid <?php if($categoryCount>4){ echo 'slider-carousel'; } else { echo 'no-slider'; } ?>">     
                    <?php $increment =1; 
                    foreach ( $bestSellingCollection as $_bestSellingCollection ) { ?>
                        <div class="slider <?php if($increment==4) { echo 'last';} ?>">

                            <div class="product_image_div">
                              <?php
                                /**
                                 * Display product image
                                 */
                                ?>
                                 <a href="<?php echo $_bestSellingCollection->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_bestSellingCollection->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                                    <?php $_imgSize = 260; ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_bestSellingCollection, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_bestSellingCollection, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                                </a>
                        <h3 class="product-name">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_bestSellingCollection->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                               <?php $prName = $_bestSellingCollection->getName ();
                                    $lenPrName = strlen ( $_bestSellingCollection->getName () );
                                    $subPrName = substr ( $prName, 0, 26 );
                                    if ($lenPrName >= 26) {
                                        $prNameFix = $subPrName . "...";
                                    } else {
                                        $prNameFix = $prName;
                                    }
                                    echo $prNameFix;?>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="products_gridview_page">
                            <div class="price-box">
                                <span class="regular-price"> 
                                    <span class="price">
                                <?php
                                    /**
                                     * Display Product Price
                                     */
                        $newPrice = $_bestSellingCollection->getPrice ();
                        $newSplPrice = $_bestSellingCollection->getSpecialPrice ();
                        $newDealExpireDate = $_bestSellingCollection->getspecial_to_date ();
                        if (! empty ( $newSplPrice ) && ($newDealExpireDate != '') && ($newDealExpireDate >= $currentDate)) {   
                            echo Mage::helper ( 'core' )->currency ( $newSplPrice, true, false );
                        } else {
                            echo Mage::helper ( 'core' )->currency ( $newPrice, true, false );
                        }
                        ?>
                                   </span>
                               </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        /**
                         * Display Add to cart, add to wishlist and compare
                         */
                        ?>
                            <div class="actions">

                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <li>
                                    <a  href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_bestSellingCollection) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>"  class="link-wishlist <?php echo $class; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="separator">|</span> 

                                    <a href="<?php 
                                    echo Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_bestSellingCollection);
                                    ?>" class="link-compare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>">

                                        <?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>               
                                 <?php if($_bestSellingCollection->isSaleable()){ ?>
                                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_bestSellingCollection) ?>')">
                                        <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
                                    </button>
                                <?php } else {?>
                                    <p class="availability out-of-stock">
                                        <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
                                    </p>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>                  
                        <?php
                        /**
                         * Check product is set as new or not
                         */
                        ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('marketplace/marketplace')->getLabel($_bestSellingCollection);  ?> 
                     </div> 
                     </div>         
                    <?php $increment++; } ?>                                
                </div>  
                <?php } 
                else {          
                    echo $this->__("No bestselling product[s] available to show");
                }?>
            </div>

        <div id="newproducts">
                    <?php $newProducts = $this->getNewproduct ();
                    $newCount = count ( $newProducts );
                    if ($newCount >= 1) {?>

                    <div class="products-grid <?php if($newCount>4){ echo 'slider-carousel'; } else { echo 'no-slider'; } ?>">
                    <?php $increment =1;    
                    foreach ( $newProducts as $new ) {      ?>
                             <div class="slider <?php if($increment==4) { echo 'last';} ?>">                    

                            <?php   $newproduct = $this->helper ( 'catalog/image' )->init ( $new, 'small_image' )->constrainOnly ( TRUE )->keepAspectRatio ( FALSE )->keepFrame ( FALSE )->resize ( 226, 226 );?>  
                            <?php
                            /**
                             * Display New Products of this seller
                             */
                            ?>    


                        <div class="product_image_div">
                        <a href="<?php echo $new->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($new->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                                    <?php $_imgSize = 260; ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($new, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($new, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                                </a>


                        <div class="products-grid-details">
                            <h2 class="product-name">
                                <a href="<?php echo $new->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                                            <?php
                            $newProductName = $new->getName ();
                            $newLengthProductName = strlen ( $new->getName () );
                            $newSubProductName = substr ( $newProductName, 0, 26 );
                            if ($newLengthProductName >= 26) {
                                $newProductNameFix = $newSubProductName . "...";
                            } else {
                                $newProductNameFix = $newProductName;
                            }
                            echo $newProductNameFix;
                            ?>

                                        </a>
                            </h2>


                                </div>
                        <div class="products_gridview_page">
                            <div class="price-box">
                                <span class="regular-price"> <span class="price">

                                                <?php
                            /**
                             * Display Product Price
                             */
                            $newPrice = $new->getPrice ();
                            $newSplPrice = $new->getSpecialPrice ();
                            $newDealExpireDate = $new->getspecial_to_date ();
                            if (! empty ( $newSplPrice ) && ($newDealExpireDate != '') && ($newDealExpireDate >= $currentDate)) {

                                echo Mage::helper ( 'core' )->currency ( $newSplPrice, true, false );
                            } else {
                                echo Mage::helper ( 'core' )->currency ( $newPrice, true, false );
                            }
                            ?>
                                            </span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>        

                    </div>
                                <?php
                            /**
                             * Display Add to cart, add to wishlist and compare
                             */
                            ?>
                             <div class="actions">
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <li><a
                                href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($new) ?>"
                                title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>"
                                class="link-wishlist <?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a
                                href="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($new);  ?>" class="link-compare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>

                        </ul>
                       <?php if($new->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button"
                            title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>"
                            class="button btn-cart"
                            onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($new) ?>')">
                            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
                        </button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock">
                            <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
                        </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                            /**
                             * Check product is set as new or not
                             */
                            ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('marketplace/marketplace')->getLabel($new);  ?>                        
                            </div>   
                        <?php $increment++; } ?>
             </div>
          <?php } 
          else {

                echo $this->__("No new product[s] available to show");
                }?> 
</div>

<div id ="deal">


<?php $products = $this->getProductCollection()->setPageSize(100);
$coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
$class = '';
 if (count($products) > 0){ ?>


<div class="products-grid <?php if(count($products)>4){ echo 'slider-carousel-deal'; } else { echo 'no-slider'; } ?>">  
    <?php $i = 1;  
    foreach ($products as $item){ ?>
                <div class="slider <?php if($i==4) { echo 'last';} ?>"> 
                    <?php
                    $originalPrice = $item->getPrice(); 
                    $discountPrice = $item->getSpecialPrice(); 
                    $savings = $originalPrice - $discountPrice; 
                    $savingsPercentage = round(($savings / $originalPrice) * 100, 0);
                    for ($increment = 0; $increment < 1; $increment++) { ?>                       
                          <div class="product_image_div">
                          <?php 
                          /**
                           * Display product image
                           */
                          ?>
                            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl() ?>" >
                               <?php $_imgSize = 260; ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($item, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                            </a>
                             <h3 class="product-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                           <?php
                           $prName = $item->getName();
                           $lenPrName = strlen($item->getName());
                           $subPrName = substr($prName, 0, 26);
                            if ($lenPrName >= 26) {
                               $prNameFix = $subPrName . "...";
                            } else {
                               $prNameFix = $prName;
                            }
                               echo $prNameFix;
                            ?>
                        </a>
                </h3>
                <?php 
                    /**
                     * Display of price details
                     */
                    ?>
                            <div class="product-details">

                            <?php if($item->getPrice() > $item->getSpecialPrice()){ ?>

                                <span class="original_price"> 
                                    <?php echo $coreHelper->currency($item->getPrice(), true, false); ?>
                                </span> 
                                <span class="offer_price"> 
                                    <?php echo $coreHelper->currency($item->getSpecialPrice(), true, false); ?>
                                </span>                                
                                <span class="discount_label">
                                     <?php echo $this->__('Discount: ') ?> 
                                </span> 
                                <span class="discount_price" <?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>>
                                      <?php echo $savingsPercentage, '%';?>
                                      <?php echo $this->__('Off');
                                      ?>
                                </span>

                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                <span> 
                                    <?php echo $coreHelper->currency($item->getPrice(), true, false); ?>
                                </span> 
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php 
                            /**
                             * Display Add to cart, add to wishlist and compare
                             */
                            ?>  <div class="actions">
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                              <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($item) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" class="link-wishlist <?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php 
                            $_compareUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($item);
                            echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                       <?php if($item->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                    /**
                     * Check product is set as new or not
                     */
                    ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('marketplace/marketplace')->getLabel($item);  ?>
                </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                     </div>
                    <?php $i++; } ?>


            <script>
                decorateList('best-sidebar', 'none-recursive');
            </script>               
            </div>
 <?php } ?>

<div id="feature">



</div>


</div>




    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add **addAttributeToFilter** to the collection for **feature** attribute like

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('feature', array('eq' => 'Yes')); // or 0 or 1 iff you are using Boolean values

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    //var_dump($product);
    var_dump($product->getData());
}
```

Comment: Product Collection is uses EAV so, it you can not use addFieldToFilter, You need to use addAttributeToFIlter.

Comment: and where did i used "addFieldToFilter" ?

Comment: On the very first line of your answer.

Comment: my bad , code is correct though. rather than down voting could have edited it :p

Comment: Sure, i will upvote, and edit your answer.